# Enabling xml-rpc on Digital Ocean marketplace Wordpress app

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, wordpress, ubuntu-18.04, xmlrpc

I've installed the Wordpress app from the Digital Ocean marketplace and want to enable xml-rpc to use with the Wordpress app (through JetPack), which requires the xml-rpc endpoint. But I'm having trouble with figuring out how they have disabled that.

The relevant php-modules seems to be installed:

```
# apt list php*xmlrpc
Listing... Done
php-xmlrpc/bionic,now 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 all [installed]
php7.2-xmlrpc/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

I've got a feeling that the problem is with the .htaccess (below), but I'm not very well versed in that and can't seem to understand what directives takes precedence when using .htaccess.

Furthermore I've tried - shortly - to remove the .htaccess completely and restarting apache without it and that didn't help.

Default .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any ideas or experience with this?

Comment: AFAIK the xmlrpc interface of WordPress does not need the PHP xmlrpc module. And the functionality is enabled by default in WordPress. You should be able to use it without doing anything.

Comment: Hi @GeraldSchneider, Digital Ocean [explicitly states](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/wordpress) that they've disabled xml-rpc, but does not say how...

Comment: You really should have a chat with Digital Ocean about their setup.

Comment: Most probably they disabled it with [WordPress methods](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/disable-xml-rpc/trunk/disable-xml-rpc.php).

Comment: "I've got a feeling that the problem is with the .htaccess" - Just for the record... this has nothing to do with the `.htaccess` file you posted.

Comment: Thanks, @MrWhite. I'll cross that off the list then. :)

Comment: Yeah, @MichaelHampton, I'm trying that too. But at first they reported my forum post as spam and after they unblocked it it's not generating any answers...

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Do you have any idea where I'd find something like that? There's no plugin with any mention of xml-rpc...

Comment: FWIW: asked this at the DigitalOcean forums: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-use-the-1-click-wordpress-install-with-the-ios-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the xml-rpc.php block in the Wordpress one-click image at DigitalOcean, run these commands over SSH/console:

```
a2disconf block-xmlrpc
systemctl reload apache2
```

That should have you taken care of.

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks a bunch. :)

Comment: After running these, I still get the same error from the wordpress iOS app, "Couldn't connect. Required XML-RPC methods are missing on the server."

Comment: Similar situation as @AdamGrant, tried this (i.e. `a2disconf ...` and reload) and still get the same error!

Comment: It's 2024 and this worked for me. After running it, the server tells you to run the second part too. Good stuff.